# Printing shortest path from unweighted graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I have an oriented graph represented as Adjacency List :

[image]

```
class Graph
{
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Node *next;
            int vertex;
            Node( int vertex )
            {
                this -> vertex = vertex;
                this -> next = nullptr;
            }
        };

        Node ** graph;
        int V;

public:
    Graph(int size)
    {
        V = size;
        graph = new Node*[V];
        for ( int i = 0; i < V; i++ )
            graph[i] = nullptr;
    }

   // Add edge from Source to destination
   void addEdge( int source, int destination )  
   {
      Node * ref = graph[from];
      graph[from] = new Node( to );
      graph[from] -> next = ref;
   }

  void bfs ( int s, int dest )
  {
   // ...
  }
```

I have implemented bfs which gives me the shortest path from node A to node B but I don't know how to effectively save that path and then print it. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: why don't you show us how you implemented bfs and it will be easier to help you figure out how to save your results.

Comment: @xaxxon updated bfs

Comment: I recommend creating a "came from" map that stores how you got to each node.   Then just use that map to walk backwards when you reach your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you perform a BFS starting at node A all the nodes you visit may have multiple childs but each has only one parent. As you go through the graph just save the parent of each node you visit (which has not been visited yet).

When you find node B just look up its parent and then its parent's parent and so on. This gives you the path.

Comment: addEdge( 0, 1 ) , addEdge( 0, 2 ); that means 0 is the source and parent of both 1 and 2 so graph[0] is pointer to linked list of 2 nodes named 0 and 1 how do i save pointer to parent when parent is actually not created it's just a pointer

Comment: @paxie You have the array visited, you can add another one, which contains the parent. The parent here means the node from which you visited the node, so basically it should be `visited[*i] = true; parent[*i]=s;`

Comment: Use another data structure to store the parent relation. An array `a` for example where `a[1] = 0` and `a[2]=0` then you can just jump through the array.